# Displaying ImageIcon on Swing components

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, imageicon

I am trying to use this for a Minesweeper game.

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
public class Testing extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private ImageIcon icon;
    public Testing() {
        initComponents();
        icon = new ImageIcon("flag.gif");
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.FlowLayout());

    jLabel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(32, 32));
    getContentPane().add(jLabel);

    jButton.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(32, 32));
    jButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(jButton);

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        
private void jButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        //diplay the icon
        jButton.setIcon(icon);
        jLabel.setIcon(icon);
}                                       
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       /* Create and display the form */
       java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               new Testing().setVisible(true);
           }
       });
   }
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

I need to be able to display the image on a button, but I cant even get it on the label.  The image is in the same file as the class files and is 32x32.

Comment: did you shake it a little bit?? usually they dont fit. just give it a good shake

Comment: *"The image is in the same file as the class files"* - Then you should be using something more like `icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("flag.gif"));` instead, `ImageIcon(String)` assumes that the file is located on the disk, which isn't true for embedded resources. I'd also encourage you to use `ImageIO.read` instead as it will throw an `IOException` when the image can't be loaded

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Your code worked perfectly fine for me. Your issue is almost certainly in this line pointing to the wrong file location. Make absolutely sure that flag.gif is in the root directory of your project, not necessarily in the same directory as your class:

```
icon = new ImageIcon("flag.gif");
```

Best of luck